# Delphi: What is the good way to convert an Uint64 to an int64?

Tags: delphi

What is the most efficient way to convert an UInt64 to an int64 ? it's important that it's work the same for any versions of delphi in any system (android/windows/ios/etc)

right now i simply do :

```
function Uint64toInt64(const aValue: UInt64): int64;
begin
  result := aValue;
end;
```

and value like 9223372036854775808 is converted to -9223372036854775808 and it's fine, but i m worry if it's will the same result in any computer/system

Comment: Not all versions of Delphi support `UInt64`. It was first added in D7 but was just an alias for `Int64`. It was not a distinct type until D2006. The real question is, why do you need to convert a `UInt64` to `Int64` in the first place? What are you trying to accomplish with it? Why is cross-platform consistency across different architectures important? What does the `UInt64` represent and how will the `Int64` be used that the `UInt64` can't do?

Comment: Can you define how the conversion should work

Comment: thanks remy, i need to convert because database does not support uint64 ...

Comment: @loki: Then I would use `Result := PInt64(@aValue)^;` so no actual *conversion* is performed. The result will have the exact same bits, they would just be *interpretted* differently if the value is evaluated. Going back the other way, you could then use `Result := PUInt64(@aValue)^;` when `aValue` is an `Int64` and `Result` is a `UInt64`.

Comment: You still have not defined the desired conversion

Comment: thanks remy, i will do like this :)